# What does this Matlab code do?

Tags: matlab

I don't understand what is the meaning of variable "samples":

```
filename = 'A2D.bin' ;
fid = fopen(filename) 
data = fread(fid , 'uint8') ;
num_of_bits = 8 ;
samples = data * 2 / (2^num_of_bits - 1) - 1 ;
fclose(fid) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is essentially reading in a data file called `A2D.bin` where the elements are stored in an array called `data`.  However, note that the `fread` call is assuming each chunk of 8 bits is unsigned and denotes one number in your array.  This means that your data is originally containing numbers from `[0,255]`.  `samples` simply normalizes this data so that it's in the range of `[-1,1]`.

Break the steps down logically.  Doing `data / (2^num_of_bits - 1)` is doing `data / 255` which normalizes your data so that it has a range of `[0,1]`.  Multiplying the result by 2, or doing `data * 2 / (2^num_of_bits - 1)` thus scales your data so that the range is now `[0,2]`.  Finally when you subtract 1 at the end of the statement, doing `data * 2 / (2^num_of_bits - 1) - 1;` finally brings your data down by shifting down by -1, which makes your data become `[-1,1]`.

Judging from the file name, this probably is the output of an analog to digital converter and you would like what the analog equivalent of each digital block of 8 bits was.  Judging from the dynamic range of `[-1,1]`, the data was most likely originating from some sort of audio file where each sample is transformed from a continuous (i.e. analog) representation into digital form.